# need to convert sql query to linq and return list of records

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

Hai using sql query its working database side, directly did not database because it code first approach. so i need following sql query convert to linq query. please any one suggest me .

```
SELECT  Sy.SystemUserName,
    MIN(Sc.CreatedOn) as StartedTime,   
    MAX(Sc.CreatedOn) as ExitTime,
    datediff(MINUTE, 
    MIN(Sc.CreatedOn) , 
    MAX(Sc.CreatedOn)) as WorkingHours  
 from SystemDetails Sy   
 LEFT JOIN Screenshots Sc on Sy.id = Sc.SystemId   
 where Sy.CompanyGUID =  '25' 
 AND  Sy.IsDeleted = 0
 and (datediff(dd,Sc.CreatedOn,getdate()) = 0
 Or SC.CreatedOn IS NULL) 
 GROUP By Sy.SystemUserName
```

SystemDetails Model :

```
 public class SystemDetails 
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string GuidID { get; set; }

   
    [Required]
    public string SystemUserName { get; set; }

  
    [Required]
    public string CompanyGUID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int TeamId { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Screenshot> Screenshot { get; set; }
 

   }
```

Screenshot Model :

```
  public class Screenshot 
    {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string GuidId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int SystemId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Screenshotname { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public SystemDetails System { get; set; }

}
```

Return collection Class :

```
   public class UserAttendance
     {
    public string StaffName { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

    public string WorkingHours { get; set; }

     }
```

Here SystemDetails table Systemusername and Screenshot table CreatedOn fields we needed, SystemDeatils Id field and Screenshot SystemId field are key constraint. Need to get SystemUserName and Minimum CreatedOn date as StartTime, Maximum CreatedOn Date as EndTime. we get both datetime duration as WorkingHours. we have get all values using ef core. Incase CreatedOn date null or no date avilable then return '1900-01-01' default date.  Please suggest me

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider? What are your classes / models?

Comment: We are using EF 3.1 and two models below lists are  => SystemDetails models are       public class SystemDetails 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string GuidID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string SystemIP { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string SystemUserName { get; set; }

         [Required]
        public string CompanyGUID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int TeamId { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }  public ICollection<Screenshot> Screenshot { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Here are the models and returned collection class are        public class UserAttendance
    {
        public string StaffName { get; set; }

        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
        public string WorkingHours { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Screenshot models are =>  public class Screenshot
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string GuidId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int SystemId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Screenshotname { get; set; }

        public SystemDetails System { get; set; }     public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
 }

Comment: Update question, not comments. Have you tried to use `GroupBy`?

Comment: ok will update now. Yes am  used GroupBy

Comment: Show your attempts and which problems do you have. This query is easy to translate and SO is not free SQL to LINQ translation service.

Comment: Yes i get all fields easy. i dont know how to use sql function here. like MAX,MIN, DateDiff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```cs
var query = 
    from sy in dbContext.SystemDetails
    from sc in sy.Screenshot
    where sy.CompanyGUID == "25" && !sy.IsDeleted
       && (sc.CreatedOn == null || EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(sc.CreatedOn.Value, DateTime.Now) == 0)
    group sc by new { sc.SystemUserName } into g 
    select new UserAttendance
    {
        StaffName = g.Key.SystemUserName,
        StartTime = g.Min(x => x.CreatedOn.Value),
        EndTime = g.Max(x => x.CreatedOn.Value),
        WorkingHours = EF.Functions.DateDiffMinute(g.Min(x => x.CreatedOn.Value), g.Max(x => x.CreatedOn.Value)).ToString()
    };
```

Comment: This is working fine sir. Thanks lot. here face a new problem. what are is systemdetails   table have five records, this records have only 3 records screenshots createdon datetime value field. other 2 rows createdon field value empty. in this scenario, need to five records  if createdon value empty then show default date. now createdon date available  3 rows records only came. but need to five rows. Once again thanks your replays